# Disable tail calls to a function in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, optimization, visual-studio-2015, tail-call-optimization

How can I disable tail calls to a specific function in Visual Studio?
The reason I need this is because I have a function that breaks to the debugger that I use when an error occurs and I need to see what function called it.
I cannot change global optimization options because the project runs too slow without optimizations.

Comment: Can't you disable optimization on that specific function using `#pragma optimize`?

Comment: You are breaking to the debugger in *optimized* builds? Even if you disable tail-call recursion, I can't imagine that will be very productive. Why don't you do your debugging in debugging builds with optimization disabled, and then turn on optimization (including tail-call recursion) when the code has its bugs worked out?

Comment: @CodeGray: I said I cannot run a debug build because it's too slow. And debugging an optimized build is pretty easy.

Answer (score 0):

(I'm assuming you're writing in C, because you failed to indicate the language or give any code.)

One way to ensure that an optimizing C compiler doesn't convert a Tail-Recursive Call into a jump would be to call through a function pointer variable.  Set the function pointer equal to the function you want to recursively call, declare it `volatile` to keep the optimizer from outsmarting you, and replace

```
return x * factorial(x-1);
```

with

```
static int (*volatile factorial_fp)(int) = factorial;

return x * (*factorial_fp)(x-1);
```